# ¿Cómo convertir las letras acentuadas a mayúsculas en C?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
int main (){
    FILE *ArchIn, *ArchOut;
    char NomArchIn[100], NomArchOut[100], renglon[150];
    printf ("Archivo de texto de entrada: ");
    gets (NomArchIn);
    ArchIn = fopen (NomArchIn, "rt");

    printf ("Archivo de texto de salida: ");
    gets (NomArchOut);
    ArchOut = fopen (NomArchOut, "wt");

    while (!feof(ArchIn)){
        fgets (renglon, sizeof(renglon), ArchIn);
        strupr (renglon);
        fputs (renglon, ArchOut);
    }
    fclose (ArchIn);
    fclose (ArchOut);
}
```

En este código me convierte todas las letras a mayúsculas, excepto las acentuadas y la ñ. ¿Me podrían ayudar a complementar el programa para que lo haga?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `strupr()` [no pertenece al estándar ANSI](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/), por lo que el código que generes usando esa función podría no ser portable.

Te recomiendo realizar la tarea con una biblioteca de funciones que soporte la conversión para el juego de caracteres que use tu aplicación (UTF-8 o Unicode).

Para C hay dos funciones, principalmente, que pueden ayudarte con el trabajo:

- Glib: [`g-utf8-strup()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-strup) forma parte del [conjunto de herramientas de manipulación de cadenas](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html).
- ICU: [`u_strToUpper()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#a14740e3b734ffa82205d4762fcacb5e1) forma parte de las funciones de [gestión de cadenas Unicode `ustring.h`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html).

Para convertir de ISO-8859-1 a UTF-8 se puede hacer uso de este breve trozo de código:

```
unsigned char *entrada, *salida;
while (*entrada) {
  if (*entrada < 0x80) {
    *salida++ = *entrada++;
  } else {
    *salida++ = 0xc2 + (*entrada > 0xbf);
    *salida++ = (*entrada++ & 0x3f) + 0x80;
  }
```

Teniendo en cuenta que la cadena de salida tiene que tener reservado el doble de tamaño que el de entrada (el peor de los casos).

Con ICU deberás convertir de UFT-8 a Unicode y luego de vuelta a UTF-8 usando primero [`u_strFromUTF8()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#a5f9ff224b11166a106d1b3ac26454cd4), luego la conversión de mayúsculas/minúsculas y luego [`u_strToUTF8()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#a0ca7af2cf47b116454eed92331594afa).

---

Si usas ISO-8859-15 como codificación de caracteres puedes usar esta sencilla función que traslada los caracteres de la tabla mayúsculas a minúsculas y viceversa:

**main.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "conversion.iso-8859-15.c"

void convertir_minusculas(char* buffer) {
  unsigned char* indice;
  while (*buffer) {
    indice = strchr(mayusculas, *buffer);
    if (indice != NULL) {
      *buffer = minusculas[indice - mayusculas];
    }
    buffer++;
  }
}

void convertir_mayusculas(char* buffer) {
  unsigned char* indice;
  while (*buffer) {
    indice = strchr(minusculas, *buffer);
    if (indice != NULL) {
      *buffer = mayusculas[indice - minusculas];
    }
    buffer++;
  }
}

void main(void) {
  char buffer[250];
  printf("%s\n%s\n", mayusculas, minusculas);
  while (!feof(stdin)) {
    fgets(buffer, 250, stdin);
    convertir_minusculas(buffer);
    puts(buffer);
    convertir_mayusculas(buffer);
    puts(buffer);
    *buffer = 0;
  }
}
```

**conversion.iso-8859-15.c**

```
unsigned char mayusculas[] = {
  0x41, // 0x0041 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
  0xC6, // 0x00C6 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE
  0xC1, // 0x00C1 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
  0xC2, // 0x00C2 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xC4, // 0x00C4 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
  0xC0, // 0x00C0 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
  0xC5, // 0x00C5 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE
  0xC3, // 0x00C3 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE
  0x42, // 0x0042 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
  0x43, // 0x0043 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
  0xC7, // 0x00C7 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
  0x44, // 0x0044 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
  0x45, // 0x0045 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
  0xD0, // 0x00D0 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH
  0xC9, // 0x00C9 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
  0xCA, // 0x00CA # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xCB, // 0x00CB # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS
  0xC8, // 0x00C8 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH GRAVE
  0x46, // 0x0046 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
  0x47, // 0x0047 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
  0x48, // 0x0048 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
  0x49, // 0x0049 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
  0xCD, // 0x00CD # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE
  0xCE, // 0x00CE # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xCF, // 0x00CF # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS
  0xCC, // 0x00CC # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH GRAVE
  0x4A, // 0x004A # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
  0x4B, // 0x004B # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
  0x4C, // 0x004C # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
  0x4D, // 0x004D # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
  0x4E, // 0x004E # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
  0xD1, // 0x00D1 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE
  0x4F, // 0x004F # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
  0xD3, // 0x00D3 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH ACUTE
  0xD4, // 0x00D4 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xD6, // 0x00D6 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS
  0xD2, // 0x00D2 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH GRAVE
  0xD8, // 0x00D8 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE
  0xD5, // 0x00D5 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH TILDE
  0x50, // 0x0050 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
  0x51, // 0x0051 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
  0x52, // 0x0052 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
  0x53, // 0x0053 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
  0x54, // 0x0054 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
  0xDE, // 0x00DE # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER THORN
  0x55, // 0x0055 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
  0xDA, // 0x00DA # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH ACUTE
  0xDB, // 0x00DB # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xDC, // 0x00DC # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
  0xD9, // 0x00D9 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH GRAVE
  0x56, // 0x0056 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
  0x57, // 0x0057 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
  0x58, // 0x0058 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
  0x59, // 0x0059 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
  0xDD, // 0x00DD # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH ACUTE
  0xBE, // 0x0178 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS
  0x5A, // 0x005A # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
  0    // Fin de cadena
};
unsigned char minusculas[] = {
  0x61, // 0x0061 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A
  0xE6, // 0x00E6 # LATIN SMALL LETTER AE
  0xE1, // 0x00E1 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
  0xE2, // 0x00E2 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xE4, // 0x00E4 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
  0xE0, // 0x00E0 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
  0xE5, // 0x00E5 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE
  0xE3, // 0x00E3 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE
  0x62, // 0x0062 # LATIN SMALL LETTER B
  0x63, // 0x0063 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C
  0xE7, // 0x00E7 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
  0x64, // 0x0064 # LATIN SMALL LETTER D
  0x65, // 0x0065 # LATIN SMALL LETTER E
  0xF0, // 0x00F0 # LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH
  0xE9, // 0x00E9 # LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
  0xEA, // 0x00EA # LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xEB, // 0x00EB # LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS
  0xE8, // 0x00E8 # LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE
  0x66, // 0x0066 # LATIN SMALL LETTER F
  0x67, // 0x0067 # LATIN SMALL LETTER G
  0x68, // 0x0068 # LATIN SMALL LETTER H
  0x69, // 0x0069 # LATIN SMALL LETTER I
  0xED, // 0x00ED # LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE
  0xEE, // 0x00EE # LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xEF, // 0x00EF # LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS
  0xEC, // 0x00EC # LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH GRAVE
  0x6A, // 0x006A # LATIN SMALL LETTER J
  0x6B, // 0x006B # LATIN SMALL LETTER K
  0x6C, // 0x006C # LATIN SMALL LETTER L
  0x6D, // 0x006D # LATIN SMALL LETTER M
  0x6E, // 0x006E # LATIN SMALL LETTER N
  0xF1, // 0x00F1 # LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE
  0x6F, // 0x006F # LATIN SMALL LETTER O
  0xF3, // 0x00F3 # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE
  0xF4, // 0x00F4 # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xF6, // 0x00F6 # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS
  0xF2, // 0x00F2 # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH GRAVE
  0xF8, // 0x00F8 # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE
  0xF5, // 0x00F5 # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH TILDE
  0x70, // 0x0070 # LATIN SMALL LETTER P
  0x71, // 0x0071 # LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
  0x72, // 0x0072 # LATIN SMALL LETTER R
  0x73, // 0x0073 # LATIN SMALL LETTER S
  0x74, // 0x0074 # LATIN SMALL LETTER T
  0xFE, // 0x00FE # LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN
  0x75, // 0x0075 # LATIN SMALL LETTER U
  0xFA, // 0x00FA # LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE
  0xFB, // 0x00FB # LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  0xFC, // 0x00FC # LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
  0xF9, // 0x00F9 # LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH GRAVE
  0x76, // 0x0076 # LATIN SMALL LETTER V
  0x77, // 0x0077 # LATIN SMALL LETTER W
  0x78, // 0x0078 # LATIN SMALL LETTER X
  0x79, // 0x0079 # LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
  0xFD, // 0x00FD # LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH ACUTE
  0xFF, // 0x00FF # LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS
  0x7A, // 0x007A # LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
  0    // Fin de cadena
};
```

El resultado de una ejecución de prueba es:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main && \
  echo "Esto es áëpËÉñíÑ¡ prueba" | \
  iconv --from utf-8 --to iso-8859-15 | \
  ./main | \
  iconv --from iso-8859-15 --to utf-8

AÆÁÂÄÀÅÃBCÇDEÐÉÊËÈFGHIÍÎÏÌJKLMNÑOÓÔÖÒØÕPQRSTÞUÚÛÜÙVWXYÝŸZ
aæáâäàåãbcçdeðéêëèfghiíîïìjklmnñoóôöòøõpqrstþuúûüùvwxyýÿz
esto es áëpëéñíñ¡ prueba
ESTO ES ÁËPËÉÑÍÑ¡ PRUEBA
```

Como uso linux (ubuntu) he de convertir el texto de UTF-8 (juego de caracteres nativo) a ISO-8859-15 con `iconv --from utf-8 --to iso-8859-15`, ejecutar el programa que hace la conversión, y posteriormente volver a convertirlo a UTF-8 con `iconv --from iso-8859-15 --to utf-8` para poder verlo bien en la consola.

Por si te interesa, el archivo lo he generado de la siguiente manera:

```
#! /bin/bash

curl "https://opensource.apple.com/source/cups/cups-136.9/cups/data/iso-8859-15.txt.auto.html" > "iso-8859-15.txt"
sed -nr 's/^.*0x00.*LATIN (SMALL|CAPITAL) (LETTER .+)$/\2/gp' "iso-8859-15.txt" | sort | uniq > "iso-8859-15.txt.letras"

echo "unsigned char mayusculas[] = {" > mayusculas.txt
echo "unsigned char minusculas[] = {" > minusculas.txt

while read -r letra
do
        if [ $(grep "$letra$" "iso-8859-15.txt" | wc -l) -eq 2 ]
        then
                echo "Analizando '$letra'"
                read -r hexa resto <<< $(grep "SMALL $letra$" "iso-8859-15.txt")
                printf "  %-4s // %s\n" "${hexa}," "$resto" >> minusculas.txt
                read -r hexa resto <<< $(grep "CAPITAL $letra$" "iso-8859-15.txt")
                printf "  %-4s // %s\n" "${hexa}," "$resto" >> mayusculas.txt
        else
                echo "**FALTA $letra"
        fi
done < "iso-8859-15.txt.letras"

echo -e "  0    // Fin de cadena\n};" >> mayusculas.txt
echo -e "  0    // Fin de cadena\n};" >> minusculas.txt

cat mayusculas.txt minusculas.txt > "conversion.iso-8859-15.c"
```